# To find value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)..(n+k-1)}$ and show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^k}$ converges for $k\geq2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I know for $n=2,$ it's $1$, for $n=3$, it's $1/4$. But how to generalize and then prove? Pls let me know if you're unable to see the image attached.  [image]

> Let $k\geq2$ be a natural number. Find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)..(n+k-1)}$

> Show using above result that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^k}$ converges for k=2,3,4,..

Comment: At least for smaller $k$ the first part (c) should be solvable using telescopic sums, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293244/compute-sum-k-1n-frac-1-kk-1 for $k=2$ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109391/calculate-s-sum-k-1n-frac-1kk1k2 for $k=3$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004004/42969

Comment: @MartinR thanks for that. How could I solve the b part?